# Check upload file validation -Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image, file, validation

Only validation check if file upload. (file exist)
if not upload file then need not check validation
(In laravel validation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should share some code so you get a better help. But you can use the `nullable` rule in order to allow empty data like this:

```
// as an example
$request->validate([
    'photo' => 'nullable|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Be more specific and add some code if you want a better answer like @nakov wrote.

You can also cast a validation when you have a file uploaded with an if statement like this:

```
if ($request->hasfile('photo')) {
    $request->validate(['photo' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png'])
}
```